# How do something similar to a getAll() when doing a select from a dbcontext

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Given the following:

```
var test = (from ex in DbContext.Exams
            where ex.UserId == "123"
            select new { }).ToList();
```

How can I convert this into the other style of LINQ?

I tried this but it does not work for me:

```
var test = DbContext.Exams
           .GetAll()
           .Where(ex => ex.UserId == "123")
           .ToList();
```

It's giving me an error with the GetAll()

Comment: Because `GetAll()` isn't a method and you don't need it either

Comment: Just remove `.GetAll()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `GetAll` method:

```
var test = DbContext.Exams
           .Where(ex => ex.UserId == "123")
           .ToList();
```

By default, `DbContext.Exams` will return an `IQueryable<Exam>` of all available `Exam` items

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `.GetAll()`

```
var test = DbContext.Exams
           .Where(ex => ex.UserId == "123")
           .ToList();
```